# Adding days to a start date to create and ending date

Tags: mysql, date, addition

I have a table with a "start_date" column which contains date and a "duration" column with numeric value. I'd like to make a query to have a column "end_date". In Excel, I would simply add the start_date column with the duration column in a end_date column in date format. I don't know how to do it with MySQL.

If I do "SELECT start_date, duration, start_date+duration AS "end_date", MySQL will treat the first two columns as numeral values and I will have absurd values for dates (2013/10/30 + 2 will result in 20131032) in the "end_date" column.

Is there a simple way to do in a MySQL query the same thing that I'm doing in an excel sheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**DATE_ADD()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT 
  start_date, 
  duration, 
  DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL duration DAY) AS end_date
```

Comment: INTERVAL should be `DAY` instead of `DAYS`

Comment: Corrected. Thank you. Was just writing some PHP where I used "days" and guess it got stuck in my head.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
DATE_ADD([Date starting with],INTERVAL [number of days] DAY);
```

You can also use month and year. [Here is the documentation on it.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the [`DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL expr unit)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)
 MySQL function.
Using it this way :

```
DATE_ADD(startdate,INTERVAL duration DAY)
```